# Return HTTP request back to calling function

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I am looking to return a JSON object from an API service HTTP_GET request method and place it in the variable this._test.

**search-component.ts**

```
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
    ...    
    this.uiQuerySettings = new querySettings(this._api);
    this._test = this.uiQuerySettings.retrieveData("route3.json");
    ...
}
```

**query-settings.ts**

```
export class querySettings {
    constructor(private _api: ApiService) { }
    /* A generic method which accepts the name of the JSON configuration
     * file that is to be retrieved from the "server".  The address to
     * the server is found in the variable in the environment variable.
     */ 
    retrieveData(jsonFile: String): any {
    console.log("You are capturing data.");
    this._api.loadData(environment.jsonAddress + jsonFile).subscribe((results) => {
        if (!environment.DEBUG)
            console.log(results);
        return results;
    });
    }
}
```

The "this._api" variable points to the service which has the method loadData.  LoadData performs a simple HTTP Get request at the provided URL.  My goal is to return "results" found in query-settings.ts and place it in a test variable called "this._test" in search-component.ts.  I am finding that due to the asynchronous calls the this._test is being set with an undefined value.  How does one utilize maps, and subscribes to accomplish this?  Is there another function that I should be using to do this?

My apologies if this is a duplication and any redirection would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: You won't be able to do that as Observable as async mechanisms. You could return the observable from `retrieveData` so that `this._test` is a observable and subsctibe to `this._test` to implement the rest of your logic

Answer (score 2):

You need to return an Observable from service and subscribe it in your component.

**query-settings.ts**

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/observable';
export class querySettings {
    constructor(private _api: ApiService) { }
    /* A generic method which accepts the name of the JSON configuration
     * file that is to be retrieved from the "server".  The address to
     * the server is found in the variable in the environment variable.
     */
    retrieveData(jsonFile: String): Observable<any> {
        console.log("You are capturing data.");
        return this._api.loadData(environment.jsonAddress + jsonFile);
    }
}
```

**search-component.ts**

```
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
...
this.uiQuerySettings = new querySettings(this._api);
this.uiQuerySettings.retrieveData("route3.json").subscribe(results => {
    if (!environment.DEBUG)
        console.log(results);
    this._test = results;
});
...
}
```

In case you are displaying "this._test" in your template file you can use "[Async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe)" instead of above mentioned way.